# Django form.is_valid() is returning false everytime

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a django application. In that, when I click on update button on index.html page, it has to redirect to a webpage showing the form with 3 fields,(title,user, body). Everytime I click on update, the form is not validating. It is always returning false. Actually if we press on the update button, the user field should show the present user's id. But it is showing default value. The body field is becoming empty every time.

forms.py:

```
class ImmediateForm(forms.ModelForm):
title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),initial="Immediate",max_length=20)
class Meta:
    model = Immediate
    fields = ['title','user','body',]
    widgets = {
        'user': TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'})
    }
```

Models.py:

```
class Immediate(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(default="Immediate",max_length=30)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField(default="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def update_immediate(request,pk):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request, 'set_goals/index.html')
else:
    print(pk)
    try:
        if request.method=='POST' :
            print('Inside if')
        immediate = Immediate.objects.get(user_id=pk)
        form = ImmediateForm(request.POST or None, instance=immediate or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("no")
            immediate = form.save(commit=False)
            immediate.user = request.user.username
            immediate.body = form.cleaned_data['body']
            immediate.save()
            return render(request, 'set_goals/detail_immediate.html', {'immediate': immediate})
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'set_goals/create_template.html', context)
    except:
        if request.method=='POST' :
            print('Inside if')
        form = ImmediateForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("yes")
            immediate = form.save(commit=False)
            immediate.user = request.user
            immediate.body = form.cleaned_data['body']
            immediate.save()
            return render(request, 'set_goals/detail_immediate.html', {'immediate': immediate})
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'set_goals/create_template.html', context)
```

And the html page where the button is:

index.html:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card mb-4">
              <div class="card-header">
    Immediate
  </div>
            <img class="card-img-top" style="width:495px;height:400px;" src="" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">Empty for now</h2>
              <p class="card-text"></p>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <a href="{% url 'set_goals:update_immediate' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Update &rarr;</a>
              <a href="{% url 'set_goals:detail_immediate' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
              </form>
                </div>

</div>
            </div>
```

What is the mistake here? Why ImmediateForm() is not working? what should be done to correct this?

Comment: Your code will generate `IndentationError`s. Please edit your code and make sure the indentation is correct. We have no way of knowing which errors are relevant and which aren't.

Comment: And why this big `try` block?

Comment: Is that `try` / `except` supposed to handle `Immediate.DoesNotExist`? It's usually a good idea to (a) limit how much code is inside the `try` and (b) explicitly catch only the exceptions you're trying to handle.

Comment: @Chris I thought Immediate.objects.get() was the problem, So i created try except block, in except block, i didn't use the immediate object. Then I came to know that it was not creating problem but the ImmediateForm().

Comment: @AkhilReddy, that's one of the problems with putting so much into the `try` / `catch` and `catch`ing all exceptions. It's hard for somebody reading the code to know its purpose.

Comment: everytime, it is not even going inside is_valid() block.

Comment: Why do you write `or None` in `request.POST or None`?

Comment: @Chris I am newbie, I am learning to write efficient code. I tried to simplify it, but i am unable to.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem iF i remove the None part, I am not able to get the 1st two fields filled up as per I specified in the model

Comment: @Chris I understood that the problem is with the form. But I am unable to understand why it is throwing error

Comment: if you use `except:` then display error. Maybe you have error which you didn't expect and it makes all problem. And if you get any error then show it in question. Always show FULL error there are many useful information.

Answer (score 1):

To debug this you can use form.errors before form.is_valid or immediately after. Then just output to the console and you look, in what a problem.

Comment: Then just output each value that comes and see what is wrong with them. If the code does not throw an exception, then the problem is exclusively in the data coming to the server.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Try to remove the foreign key field from the form. This is a not good practice. I think the problem is in this field and it does not pass correctly validation.

Comment: foreign key is in model. It should be there right? because,it is connected to user database

Comment: Then check data use this - form['field'].value()

Comment: It is printing empty line

Comment: Empty line on all fields?

Comment: I printed only body pat

Comment: Only body part is empty , other fields are getting printed

Comment: Then try set blank=True, null=True to body field in model.py and validate form after that

Comment: then also form is not validating

Comment: Now there is no access to the computer, I can not check. As suggested above, try to remove try / catch, perhaps the body field is empty from the exception that occurs.